# AWK: To divide a column in userdefined chunksize; and count+sum each entry for every chunk; give average per entry for all chunk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need help to process a column entry via awk. Below are the operations i want to try:

- To divide a column in user-defined chunk size;
- count and sum each entry for every chunk to eventually give average per entry which will be eventually the chunk size.

For instance, below is a list:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Here, I want to use a chunk size of 4 (but in my case it can vary from case to case):

- chunk1

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  ```
- chunk2

  ```
  5
  6
  7
  8
  ```
- chunk3

  ```
  9
  10
  11
  12
  ```

After processing, I would like to have:

```
5
6
7
8
```

which is the average for the entries in position 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively, across all chunks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following `awk` program would do the job. It assumes the data is stored in `data.txt` in the first column (but can easily be adapted for any other column). It also assumes there are no empty columns, and only complete chunks.

```
awk -v cs=4 '{if ((i=NR%cs)==0) {n_ch++; i=cs};buf[i]+=$1;} END{for (i=1;i<=cs;i++) printf "%d\n",buf[i]/n_ch}' data.txt
```

The chunk size is passed to `awk` via the `-v cs=size` statement.

It will, for each line, determine the "entry number within the chunk", `i`, via
`i = "line number" modulo "chunk size"`, and sum the entries into an array `buf`. Whenever one chunk is complete, the chunk counter `n_ch` is increased.

In the end, we print the average for all entry numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v cs=4 '
  BEGIN {
    "(wc -l <" ARGV[1] ")" | getline nl
    nc = sprintf("%d", nl/cs)
  }
  { a[NR%cs] += $1 }
  NR>nl-cs { print a[NR%cs]/nc } 
' file
5
6
7
8
```

- in the begin block we determine the lines in the file and store it in nl variable.
- then we get the number of chunks and store it in nc variable.
- accumulate the running sum in the array indexed on the modulus of line number % chunk size.
- then when the line number crosses the threshold of nl-cs, meaning we are entering the last chunk, we begin printinh the results.

Alternatively, if we don't want to precompute the file length and number of chunks we can do this:

```
awk -v cs=4 '
  { a[NR] = $1 }
  END {
    for (i=1; i<=cs; i++) {
      k = s = 0
      for (j=i; j<=NR; j+=cs) {
        s += a[j]; k++
      }
      print s/k
    }
  }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative `awk` that just chunks as it goes and counts elements in each chunk so if the record count is not an exact chunk multiple this doesn't matter, it's still the average

```
awk -v ch=4 '{k=(NR-1)%ch; n[k]++; un[k]+=$1}
  END{for (k in un) print "Line "k+1" has "n[k]" elements totalling "un[k]" and average "un[k]/n[k]}' file

Line 1 has 3 elements totalling 15 and average 5
Line 2 has 3 elements totalling 18 and average 6
Line 3 has 3 elements totalling 21 and average 7
Line 4 has 3 elements totalling 24 and average 8
```

Although the `END` needn't be descriptive

```
  END{for (k in un) print un[k]/n[k]}' file

5
6
7
8
```

and if you want to guarantee the output sequence

```
  END{for (k=0; k<ch; k++) print un[k]/n[k]}' file
```